# What is correct way to ensure that row is not deleted in concurrent transaction

Tags: postgresql, delete, concurrency, isolation-level

I have 2 tables:

- Parent (PK id)
- Child (PK id, parent_id)

Note that parent_id is not defined a foreign key (actually they are not parent/child, I use those names just for example).

I need to handle a case when someone inserts new Child with link to Parent's row, and someone else deletes Parent's row. I would like to avoid scenario when DB contains Child row with link to non-existent Parent.

How it works now:

```
[I1] Insertion Thread: BEGIN
[I2] Insertion Thread: SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE id = 3
[D1] Deletion Thread: BEGIN
[D2] Deletion Thread: DELETE * FROM Child WHERE parent_id = 3
[D3] Deletion Thread: DELETE * FROM Parent WHERE id = 3
[D4] Deletion Thread: COMMIT
[I3] Insertion Thread: INSERT INTO Child VALUES(default, 3)
[I4] Insertion Thread: COMMIT
```

What I've tried to do:

1. Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in insertion thread

   Disadvantage: that will lock Deletion Thread on line D3, but line D2 is already executed at that moment. After Insertion Thread is done, Deletion Thread continue from D3 and will not delete just inserted Child row.

   Solution: swap D2 and D3, so deletion from Parent goes first.

   Disadvantage: a bit fragile. Those SQL statements are called from business logic code, in different places, so it is easy to swap their order back accidentally.
2. Use `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level

   Disadvantage: it does not work as I expected. I thought it will abort Insertion Thread's transaction as selected Parent's row was deleted in another transaction, but it does not. I suppose it is because I do not perform update of Parent's row in Insertion Thread, just read.

I'm kinda OK with solution 1 or explicit row locking in the beginning of transaction, but I hope there is more correct way to achieve expected behavior. Maybe I just misused isolation level?

DB is Postgres

Comment: Why not use a referential integrity constraint to ensure referential integrity? That's what it is for, after all.

Comment: Yes, it is silly to reinvent the wheel.